# double free or corruption (!prev) error in c program

Tags: c, openmp, free, corruption

I'm getting the following type of error. It works on 1 thread but if I launch this program on 2 or more, it fails. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ind(i, j) (((i + l->nx) % l->nx) + ((j + l->ny) % l->ny) * (l->nx))
typedef struct {
    int nx, ny;
    int *u0;
    int *u1;
    int steps;
    int save_steps;
} life_t;

void life_init(const char *path, life_t *l);
void life_free(life_t *l);
void life_step(life_t *l);
//void life_save_vtk(const char *path, life_t *l);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s input file.\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    life_t l;
    //clock_t t;
    //t = clock();
    life_init(argv[1], &l);

    int i;
    char buf[100];
    for (i = 0; i < l.steps; i++) {
        /*if (i % l.save_steps == 0) {
            sprintf(buf, "life_%06d.vtk", i);
            printf("Saving step %d to '%s'.\n", i, buf);
            life_save_vtk(buf, &l);
        }*/
        life_step(&l);
    }

    life_free(&l);

    //t = clock() - t;
    //printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n", (int)t, ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}


void life_init(const char *path, life_t *l)
{
    FILE *fd = fopen(path, "r");
    assert(fd);
    assert(fscanf(fd, "%d\n", &l->steps));
    assert(fscanf(fd, "%d\n", &l->save_steps));
    printf("Steps %d, save every %d step.\n", l->steps, l->save_steps);
    assert(fscanf(fd, "%d %d\n", &l->nx, &l->ny));
    printf("Field size: %dx%d\n", l->nx, l->ny);

    l->u0 = (int*)calloc(l->nx * l->ny, sizeof(int));
    l->u1 = (int*)calloc(l->nx * l->ny, sizeof(int));

    int i, j, r, cnt;
    cnt = 0;
    while ((r = fscanf(fd, "%d %d\n", &i, &j)) != EOF) {
        l->u0[ind(i, j)] = 1;
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("Loaded %d life cells.\n", cnt);
    fclose(fd);
}

void life_free(life_t *l)
{
    free(l->u0);
    free(l->u1);
    l->nx = l->ny = 0;
}
void life_step(life_t *l)
{
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel private(i, j)
    {
        int rank = omp_get_thread_num(); 
        int size = omp_get_num_threads(); 
        int starty = (rank)*l->ny/size; 
        int endy = (rank+1)*l->ny/size;
        int startx = (rank)*l->nx/size; 
        int endx = (rank+1)*l->nx/size;
        for (j = starty; j < endy; j++) {
            for (i = startx; i < endx; i++) {
                int n = 0;
                n += l->u0[ind(i+1, j)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i+1, j+1)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i,   j+1)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i-1, j)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i-1, j-1)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i,   j-1)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i-1, j+1)];
                n += l->u0[ind(i+1, j-1)];
                l->u1[ind(i,j)] = 0;
                if (n == 3 && l->u0[ind(i,j)] == 0) {
                    l->u1[ind(i,j)] = 1;
                }
                if ((n == 3 || n == 2) && l->u0[ind(i,j)] == 1) {
                    l->u1[ind(i,j)] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        int *tmp;
        tmp = l->u0;
        #pragma omp barrier
        l->u0 = l->u1;
        #pragma omp master
        l->u1 = tmp;
    }
}
```

This error I am given:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001760270 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d053)[0x7f271d265053]
./a.out[0x400ca2]
./a.out[0x400a2e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f271d209b15]
./a.out[0x4008d9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 b6:33fa1 1967354                     /home/mpi201617/openmp/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 b6:33fa1 1967354                     /home/mpi201617/openmp/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 b6:33fa1 1967354                     /home/mpi201617/openmp/a.out
01760000-01781000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                    [heap]
7f2718000000-7f2718021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2718021000-7f271c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271c5c0000-7f271c5d5000 r-xp 00000000 b6:33fa1 524309                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f271c5d5000-7f271c7d4000 ---p 00015000 b6:33fa1 524309                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f271c7d4000-7f271c7d5000 r--p 00014000 b6:33fa1 524309                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f271c7d5000-7f271c7d6000 rw-p 00015000 b6:33fa1 524309                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f271c7e6000-7f271c7e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271c7e7000-7f271c7e8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271c7e8000-7f271d1e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271d1e8000-7f271d39f000 r-xp 00000000 b6:33fa1 526414                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f271d39f000-7f271d59f000 ---p 001b7000 b6:33fa1 526414                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f271d59f000-7f271d5a3000 r--p 001b7000 b6:33fa1 526414                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f271d5a3000-7f271d5a5000 rw-p 001bb000 b6:33fa1 526414                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f271d5a5000-7f271d5aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271d5b0000-7f271d5c6000 r-xp 00000000 b6:33fa1 526440                   /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f271d5c6000-7f271d7c6000 ---p 00016000 b6:33fa1 526440                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f271d7c6000-7f271d7c7000 r--p 00016000 b6:33fa1 526440                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f271d7c7000-7f271d7c8000 rw-p 00017000 b6:33fa1 526440                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f271d7c8000-7f271d7cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271d7d0000-7f271d7e6000 r-xp 00000000 b6:33fa1 529119                  /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7f271d7e6000-7f271d9e5000 ---p 00016000 b6:33fa1 529119                  /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7f271d9e5000-7f271d9e6000 r--p 00015000 b6:33fa1 529119                  /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7f271d9e6000-7f271d9e7000 rw-p 00016000 b6:33fa1 529119                  /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7f271d9e7000-7f271d9e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271d9e8000-7f271da09000 r-xp 00000000 b6:33fa1 529085                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f271dbfe000-7f271dc00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271dc07000-7f271dc08000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271dc09000-7f271dc0a000 r--p 00021000 b6:33fa1 529085                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f271dc0a000-7f271dc0b000 rw-p 00022000 b6:33fa1 529085                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f271dc0b000-7f271dc0d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f271dc0d000-7f271dc0e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd7be92000-7ffd7bea7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [stack]
7ffd7bfa8000-7ffd7bfaa000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: quick fix is probably to just null the pointers you call free on, right after they're free'd. Though if you have the time obviously slapping a break point in where they're free'd and following the call stack to figure out why free is being called on the same pointer is the way to go.

Comment: Have you protected `life_t l` with `mutex` to prevent multiple threads from updating it and then all threads attempting to free it?

Comment: Your swap of pointers isn't thread safe. Just do it normally in a block of 3 steps `{tmp=u0; u0=u1; u1=tmp;}` and protect this block with a `#pragma omp single`

Comment: There is absolutely no need to swap the pointers *inside* the `parallel` region. Just do it outside. Also, your code is only processing the block diagonal. Why not simply use `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)` instead or reimplementing it (wrongly)?